# Error: "not meaningful for factors" in R in the following code

Tags: r

When I run my R code I get the error "not meaningful for factors," and I am unable to debug what's the issue with the code.

When I try to run only this chunk of code it is taking ages to run, but when I run it on R markdown as a whole I am getting this error.

```
library(MCMCpack)
n<- 5
x <- c( 1.0,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5, 2.5)
y <- c(1.80, 1.85, 1.87, 1.77, 2.02)
iterations = 10000
alpha = rep(NA, iterations+1)
beta = rep(NA, iterations+1)
gamma = rep(NA, iterations+1)
tau_square = rep(NA, iterations+1)

# initial states for each parameter
alpha[1] = 2
beta[1] = 2
gamma[1] = 0.5
tau_square[1] = 0.1

# full conditional gamma
full_cond_gamma = function(gamma, alpha, beta, tau_square) {
  return(exp(-1/(2*tau_square)*sum((y-alpha+beta*gamma^x)^2)))
}

for(t in 1:iterations) {
  # update alpha Markov chain
  alpha[t+1] = rnorm(1,(10000*sum(y+beta[t]*gamma[t]^x))/(n*10000+tau_square[t]),
                     sqrt((tau_square[t]*10000)/(n*10000 + tau_square[t])))

  # update beta Markov chain
  beta[t+1] = rnorm(1,(10000*sum((alpha[t+1]-y)*gamma[t]^x)) / 
                      (10000*sum(gamma[t]^(2*x))+tau_square[t]),
                    sqrt((tau_square[t]*10000)/(10000*sum(gamma[t]^(2*x))+tau_square[t])))

  # MH to update gamma Markov chain
  proposal = runif(1,0,1) 
  prob = full_cond_gamma(proposal, alpha[t+1], beta[t+1], tau_square[t]) /
    full_cond_gamma(gamma[t], alpha[t+1], beta[t+1], tau_square[t]) 
  gamma[t+1] = ifelse(runif(1,0,1)<=prob, proposal, gamma[t])

  # update tau square markov chain
  tau_square[t+1] = rinvgamma(1, n/2 + 0.001, 
                              0.001+1/2*sum((y-alpha[t+1]+beta[t+1]*(gamma[t+1]^x))^2))

}
MG = cbind(alpha,beta, gamma, tau_square)
head(MG)
```

Comment: Please include the entire error message – it may include relevant information that you're missing

Comment: `iterations = 10000` !?!? Did you consider moving down to 10 iterations to find the bug in your code?

Comment: �^� not meaningful for factors�+� not meaningful for factorsNAs produced�-� not meaningful for factors�^� not meaningful for factors�*� not meaningful for factors�*� not meaningful for factorsNAs produced�-� not meaningful for factors�^�
alpha beta gamma tau_square
[1,]     2    2   0.5        0.1
[2,]   NaN  NaN    NA        NaN
[3,]   NaN  NaN    NA        NaN
[4,]   NaN  NaN    NA        NaN
[5,]   NaN  NaN    NA        NaN
[6,]   NaN  NaN    NA        NaN
This is what i got in the console

Comment: Oh yes for lesser value of iterations it works flawlessly, but for higher value of iterations say for  iterations = 10000 its a problem, i want to repeat for 10000 iterations